# Emoji's not getting sent from text input in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to send emoji's from input box once I click enter it's not getting sent in form of emojis it's getting converted into "??".

```html
<ion-input autocomplete="true"  spellcheck="true" class='input-cover' type="text" [(ngModel)]="userComment" placeholder="Post a Comment">
</ion-input>
```

Comment: are you sure the issue is sending from ionic and not during saving of the text in server side?

Comment: @SurajRao if I send text it's getting send and show it in comment section but if I add emoji along with text then it would be like "Congrats ???"